# Why are there three variables with `merge` method?

Tags: ruby, hash, merge

```
h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
h1.merge(h2) do |key, old, new|
  new - old
end
```

How does this code work? Why are there three variables (`key, old, new`), and where are they pointing to? How can `old` be subtracted from `new` when `new` and `old` were not defined?

Comment: Have you read [the manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge), you will learn it's: key, old value, and new value.

```
h1.merge(h2) { |key, old, new| new - old }
```

means the final result will have value `h2[key] - h1[key]`. Since you are merging `h2` over `h1`, values from `h2` will be new values and those from `h1` will be old values.